# Апостроф чи м'який знак у французьких прізвищах

Tags: власні-назви

Я зіштовхнувся з необхідністю перекласти назву захворювання внутрішнього вуха

> Meniere's disease - хвороба Мен'єра/Меньєра

Схожі прізвища зазвичай транслітеруються з м'яким знаком

> Gérard Depardieu - Жера́р Депардьє́
>
> Cardinal Richelieu - Кардинал Рішельє

У випадку цієї хвороби, більш згадуваним є версія *Мен'єра*, аніж *Меньєра*.

Буду дуже вдячний за посилання на правила транслітерації, які безпосередньо згадують про використання апострофа чи м'якого знака.

Comment: Все-таки у книжках «хвороба Меньєра» зустрічається значно частіше за «хвороба Мен'єра». Тому не бачу причин писати «хвороба Мен'єра». Хоча питання про загальне правило залишається відкритим (адже в багатьох [франзуцьких прізвищах](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Категорія:Французькі_прізвища) є й апострофи).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нема складнощів в цьому випадку, має бути Меньєр за наступним правилом:

> М’який знак пишеться після м’яких приголосних д, т, з, с, ц, л, н
>   перед я, ю, є, ї, йо

[джерело](http://shkolyar.in.ua/napysannya-sliv-inshomovnogo-pohodjennya)

Comment: Перебуквування частенько не зважають правопису. Так, це з [правопису](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par92).